# List<String> Received List<Long> in JSF 2.3

Tags: jsf, converters, jsf-2.3, selectmanycheckbox

I have Upgrade my project from JSFContainer 2.2 to JSFContainer 2.3

```
<p:selectManyListbox id="acl" value="#{controller.process.basisList}" >  
    <f:selectItems value="#{controller.filinglist}" />  
</p:selectManyListbox>
```

filinglist has class object like ob(1L, 'data1');
basisList with generic type String

when working with JSFContainer 2.2, CDI 1.2 and EL 3.0. it's working fine the Long data has been stored as String in basisList List. I understand the this concept in below URL

[Java Reflection API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21446068/listinteger-received-liststring)

But in JSFContainer 2.3, CDI 2.0 and EL 3.0. I got the below error

when I run the code

```
for(String i : basisList) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

`java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.String.`

I debug using below code

```
for(Object i : basisList) {
        System.out.println(i.getClass() + " > " + i);
    }
```

The output what am getting is below

```
class java.lang.Long > 3
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve] as requested in [ask]. IMPOSSIBLE for us to help with this piece of code. And the java tag attracts people that might not know JSF or EL. And try with a plain JSF counterpart instead of the PrimeFaces one. Does that work?

Comment: Error of this link. reversely happening for me after upgrade JSF 2.2 to JSF 2.3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21446068/listinteger-received-liststring

Comment: I understand what is happening, but please, please, please create a [mcve] with a backingbean etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior is correct when you upgrade from JSF 2.2 to JSF 2.3. Previously, JSF 2.2 and older didn't auto-convert these values which was actually **not** the expected behavior.

It's specified in [`UISelectMany` javadoc for JSF 2.3](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/faces/component/UISelectMany.html).

> Obtain the `Converter` using the following algorithm:
>
> - If the component has an attached `Converter`, use it.
> - If not, look for a `ValueExpression` for value (if any). The `ValueExpression` must point to something that is:
>
>   - An array of primitives (such as `int[]`). Look up the registered by-class `Converter` for this primitive type.
>   - An array of objects (such as `Integer[]` or `String[]`). Look up the registered by-class `Converter` for the underlying element type.
>   - A `java.util.Collection`. Do not convert the values. **Instead, convert the provided set of available options to string, exactly as done during render response, and for any match with the submitted values, add the available option as object to the collection.**
>
> If for any reason a `Converter` cannot be found, assume the type to be a String array.

The emphasized section of the above blockquote is new since JSF 2.3 (to compare, [here's the JSF 2.2 variant of `UISelectMany` javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UISelectMany.html)).

You need to fix your `basisList` to become of exactly same type as `filinglist`, or else you'll need to attach an explicit `Converter`.

Answer (score 1):

You basisList is probably of type `<Object>` so when you create your for loop with a `String` Java tries to cast that value into the String variable `i`. In your case it seems that you have a list partially, or fully filled with primitive `long` types which can't just be cast to a string. You could write some code like this which would support both cases.

```
List<Object> basisList = new ArrayList<>();

for (Object o : basisList) {
  if (o instanceof String) {
    System.out.println(o.toString());
  } else if(o instanceof Long){
    System.out.println(Long.toString((Long) o));
  } else {
    System.out.println("Some other type = " + o.toString());
  }
}
```

Comment: No. As I mentioned The basisList type is <String>. List<String> basisList = new ArrayList<String>();

Comment: Well it can't be, otherwise you'd never get that class cast exception. There are Long types in your list.

Comment: No Adam. Its working fine in JSF 2.2 right. Please read this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21446068/listinteger-received-liststring. The error of the link reversely happening for me.

Comment: Yes, but like the answers say the generic types vanish during compilation and everything is an Object and cast to the different types at run time. That class cast exception indicates to me that the list you presume contains only <String> actually has some Long values in there. I'm not familiar with how JSF works under the hood, but if you add some type checking to your method you might be able to debug what is going on.

Comment: @Adam: EL and passing from a webpage to a server might result in 'lists' being interpreted as strings. And yes, there might be something not explicit as a long but it does not have to be the list itself. OP should create a [mcve] and not have used the java tag since this cannot be reproduced in a plain jdk

Comment: Your debug just confirms what I said in my answer. Your list contains Long types. You need to iterate it as an Object list since you can't guarantee what types you are getting and perform the appropriate checks on your types before operating on them.

Comment: I understand that. But why its not happen in JSF 2.2 and why am facing error in JSF 2.3. That was my question.

Comment: @Jai: First show exactly what you did in a [mcve] There might be several reasons behaviour changed including a bug fix which you by accident (unintentionally or by some lack of knowledge) used.